# automatic login to another website

Tags: javascript, php, livechat

i want to apply olark live chat to my own website. let say my website is "A" and olark is "B". so if i access or log in to A, B will automatically login to redirect in their own page. is it possible to send user name and password and sign into B automatically?

Comment: Look into Oauth

Comment: Check for oneclicklogin mechanism

Comment: ok i will check it out! thanks!

Comment: Kindly refer to this https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server & read the documentation provided here

Comment: is it work even i'm using a localhost?

Comment: how about php curl? should i use it?